# Does anyone know why app "Recovery Partition Creator" is now an un-maintained project?

Tags: recovery

Does anyone know why app "Recovery Partition Creator" is now an un-maintained project?   I wanted something like this to use on 10.14.5  but I am noticing the app hasn't been maintained since 10.13 .   I replaced the SSD on a MacPro but had to restore it from a time machine backup and I wanted to update the recovery partition software to latest, because it comes with 10.12 I think,  if possible.

**github.com/MagerValp/Create-Recovery-Partition-Installer.git**

Is there an alternative?  I am not intending this to be an opinion generating question, but rather a technical question.

Answer (score 1):

Maggsy got a different job and got out of tech entirely.

Try this one:

http://musings.silvertooth.us/index.php/2016/10/05/recovery-partition-4-0-4/